# Defining a test source set for Intellij 15 with Gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, intellij-15

I'm able to define a `sourceSet` in Gradle using something like the following

```
sourceSets {
    unitTest {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/unitTest/java'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'src/unitTest/resources'
        }
    }
}
```

However, I do not seem to be able to define a Test source set using gradle. I can specify it manually via the UI, but when the gradle projects are refreshed, they are set again as a Source Set, rather than a Test Source Set.

Is there any way to define the source set in Gradle, and have Intellij pick up that it's a Test Source Set?

Comment: Are you using Java plugin? It automatically defines main and test sourcesets.

Comment: Java plugin is included. I wanted to break my tests up into different folders, one for integration tests, one for unit tests, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This has bugged many people, see [IDEA-165647](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-165647#comment=27-2154956). The proposed solution there, which actually works would then look as follows:

```
sourceSets {
    test.java.srcDir 'src/unitTest/java'
    test.resources.srcDir 'src/unitTest/resources'

    unitTest {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/unitTest/java'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'src/unitTest/resources'
        }
    }
}
```

The difference is to add `test.java.srcDir` and `test.resources.srcDir`.